# Run exe file in Mozilla Firefox via create Firefox extention

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Can I create Firefox extension which get value of inputExePath field in simple webpage and run exe in that path?

How do that?

Comment: yes you can do that by using system/child_process low level API

Comment: The child process is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process if you dont like that, then you can go `var myExe = new FileUtils.File('C:\\blah.exe'); var process = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess); process.init(myExe);`